# Return generic type from callback function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming, callback

I want my function to select one of several callback functions based on another argument and call it, returning its returned value. But I don't understand, how to write it in code.

I try to do it this way but this syntax is invalid:

```
const callSelectedCallback<T> = (
    callbackForPositiveValue: () => T,
    callbackForNegativeValue: () => T,
    value: number,
): T | undefined => {
    if (value > 0) {
        return callbackForPositiveValue();
    }
    if (value < 0) {
        return callbackForNegativeValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: `const callSelectedCallback = <T>(`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65948000/2947812 - after remembering that I'm dealing with *higher order functions* (keyword)

```
type CallbackSelector = <T>(
    callback1: () => T,
    callback2: () => T,
    value: number,
) => T | undefined;

const callSelectedCallback: CallbackSelector = (
    callbackForPositiveValue: () => T,
    callbackForNegativeValue: () => T,
    value: number,
) => {
    if (value > 0) {
        return callbackForPositiveValue();
    }
    if (value < 0) {
        return callbackForNegativeValue();
    }
};
```